# Fisher kernel or KL divergence?

Tags: kernel-trick, discriminant-analysis, similarities

I am currently reading about pLSA and LDA and how can I apply these methods on calculating document similarity. I got a feeling that common similarity measure used in pLSA is Fisher kernel, but for LDA I usually come across (symmetric) KL divergence. Are there special reasons not to use KL divergence in pLSA model and why?

Comment: "but for LDA I usually come across (symmetric) KL divergence." Where did you see that KL divergence in LDA ? Can you give a reference ?

Comment: E.g. http://asv.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/publication/file/210/nieklerjaehnichenICCM2012.pdf or http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/theses/ozcaglar.08.ms.pdf